# how to install Odoo 9 on ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, odoo

I have pre installed postgres , postgres-9.3 and pgadmin on port 5432 and 5433 .

uninstall them then trying to install odoo 9 using http://openies.com/blog/install-openerp-odoo-9-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts/

this tutorial .

but when i ttrying to execute command

```
createuser --createdb --username postgres --no-createrole --no-superuser --pwprompt odoo
```

then it gives following error :

> createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect
>   to server: No such file or directory  Is the server running locally
>   and accepting     connections on Unix domain socket
>   "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

**sudo netstat -nltp | grep 5432**  is not showing any result .

**pg_hba.conf**

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: You can get the installation guide [here](http://openies.com/blog/install-openerp-odoo-9-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts/) or [here](https://www.getopenerp.com/install-odoo-9-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bitnami ODOO**, easy to install in your Machine.

[Download from Here](https://bitnami.com/stack/odoo)

It is compatible with preinstall postgresql.

Answer (score 3):

**1. Introduction**

In this tutorial I will learn you how to install Odoo 9 on Ubuntu 14.04. The script that you will use is based on the code from André Schenkels but has been updated and improved.

**2. Downloading the script**

The first step is to download my script from GitHub and to add the code in a new .sh file on your Ubuntu machine, wherever you’d like this.
For example right under /home. Open up an Ubuntu terminal and cd to the directory where you’d like to keep the script and then create the file:

```
 sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript/9.0/odoo_install.sh
```

If you’re curious about how the whole code looks and works you can find it on my Github account.

Now open up the file and edit the parameters to your liking:

```
 sudo nano odoo_install.sh
```

There are some things you can configure/change to your likings at the top of the script. You can choose if you wish to install Wkhtmltopdf or not, which version you’d like, where the location is and most importantly what the master admin password is. Tip: always modify this for every Odoo you install!

**3. Making the Odoo installation file executable**

The next step is to make this file executable. After you’ve made it executable you can execute it and everything will be installed automatically.
do this with the following command:

```
sudo chmod +x odoo_install.sh
```

**4.Running the script**

Now that the code is in your file and the file is executable you simply have to execute it with the following command:

```
 ./odoo_install.sh
```

You will see that the script automatically starts updates, downloads required packages, creates the user, downloads the code from Github, …
Give the script a few minutes to configure and install everything and eventually you will see something like this:
[image]

You now have a fully functional Odoo V9 on your system! Congratulations.
Odoo V9
[image]

**5. Extra information**

In the script you saw there was an option to change the Odoo port (OE_PORT). When you’d change this port number to 8070 in the install script it would be applied to /etc/your-config-file.conf and this would give you the ability to change the default port.

**To apply these changes you should do the following:**

[image: **Changing Odoo settings**]

The -c will change the configuration and memorize what you’ve changed under /etc/your-config-file.conf. Because my port was set to 8070 this is telling the Odoo that it should run on port 8070. When you would now open up your browser and navigate to http://localhost:8070/ you will see it is running there:
Odoo V9 alternative port

Answer (score 2):

This issue comes form installing the postgres package with out a version number. Although postgres will be installed and it will be the correct version the script to setup the cluster will not be run correctly. It's a packaging issue. If your comfortable with Postgres there is a script you can run to crete this cluster and get postgres running however if your like me then you do it the easy way. First purdge the old postgres install. The issue currently lies with 9.1 so I will assume that's what you have installed

sudo apt-get remove --purge postgresql-9.1
Now simply reinstall

sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1

Note the package name with the version number. HTH.

Comment: I installed version 9.4 with name

Answer (score 2):

I have installed odoo using  http://openies.com/blog/install-openerp-odoo-9-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts/ got no issue with the fresh ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

But, you need to check that there is no `postmaster.pid` in your **postgres** directory, probably `/usr/local/var/postgres/`

Remove this and start server using

```
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
```

It should work.

Check this to [install odoo 10 in ubuntu 16.04 LTS](http://atularvind.com/pages/install-odoo-10-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before you can use one simple script to install Odoo of any version (9, 10, 11).

Follow the steps:

1. Log in to your system and work as an superuser: `sudo su`
2. Update the system: `apt-get update`
3. Download the script. You can change to the version of your choice:
   `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript/11.0/odoo_install.sh`
4. Run the script: `./odoo_install.sh`
5. Now you can access Odoo at `http://serverIP:8069`

If you are running it locally that would be `127.0.0.1:8069`

The next steps would be to configure the Apache/Nginx or another server to point a domain to the Odoo instance. Also, remember to set the proper access rules on your server (for example on Amazon that would be by opening the port 80 and 8069 in the security rules). It is also wise to change the default password in Odoo config from `admin` to something more secure.

If you used the script without editing your Odoo config file would be installed in `/etc/odoo-serfer.config`. Use `nano`, `vi` or another editor to change the default settings.